# Converting an equation to JavaScript

Tags: javascript, math

I am trying to convert this math equation into JS:

```
F(x) = 1/(x*sigma*sqrt(2*pi)*e^-(ln(x) -µ)²/(2*sigma²)
```

I think I am messing up with some of my JS:

```
var fx = 1/(x*0.24*Math.sqrt(2*Math.PI)*Math.pow(Math.E,Math.pow(-(Math.log(x)-0.1136),2)/(2*Math.pow(0.1136,2))));
```

Comment: What makes you think it's messing up? Does it not run? Do you get error messages? Does it give the wrong result?

Comment: It is obviously difficult to read your code. That is enough to qualify it as *bad*. I would suggest that you split it into readable lines of code. As soon as you are able to see what it does, you won't have questions any more ;)

Comment: You probably want a function that actually takes `x` as an input, otherwise `x` in your code will be undeclared.

Comment: *"I think I am messing up"* is not an actionable problem statement

Comment: What is the name of scripting language of the first expression??

Answer (score 0):

It looks correct

```
function fx(x){
  return 1/(x*0.24*Math.sqrt(2*Math.PI)*Math.pow(Math.E,Math.pow(-(Math.log(x)-0.1136),2)/(2*Math.pow(0.1136,2))));
}

console.log(fx(5))
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code produces an output (not NaN ;D), pls check if it is the result you want.

```
var fx = 
1 / (
    x * 0.24 * Math.sqrt(2*Math.PI) * 
    Math.pow(
        Math.E,-Math.pow(
            Math.log(x)-0.1136 , 2
        ) / ( 2 * Math.pow(0.1136,2) )
    )
);
```